# how to manage nested transaction with try catch

Tags: sql-server, try-catch, sqltransaction, savepoints, nested-transactions

```
--Drop Table Tab1

Begin Transaction TR1; 
Save Transaction TR1;
    Create Table Tab1(f1 decimal(10,0));
    Begin Transaction TR2
    Save Transaction TR2
        insert into Tab1 values(1);
        Begin Transaction TR3;
        Save Transaction TR3;
            insert into Tab1 values(2);
            Begin Try 
                insert into Tab1 values('OK');
                Commit Transaction TR3;
            END TRY
            BEGIN Catch
                print 'catch'
                RollBack Transaction TR3;
            End Catch

        insert into Tab1 values(3);
        Commit Transaction TR2
    insert into Tab1 values(4);
Commit Transaction TR1;
--Commit Transaction;
select * from Tab1;
Drop Table Tab1

Select @@TRANCount
```

Error Occures :

> Msg 3931, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
>   The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction.

How to handle this.

Comment: @mellamokb `RollBack Transaction TR3;` is the line that gives the error. If you run the code as written it's line 18

Answer (score 3):

When certain type of errors get raised you cannot rollback to a save point. See [Martin Smith's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) answer to [Rollback transaction to savepoint on failing ALTER TABLE … ADD CONSTRAINT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314568/rollback-transaction-to-savepoint-on-failing-alter-table-add-constraint/5324972#5324972). The way you detect this is to test `Xact_state()`.

However your problem is somewhat different because you're also trying to use nested transactions. Nested transactions don't really work in SQL as we would expect them to.

- You can only name the outermost transaction. [See Transactions (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190612%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

For example this fails with `Cannot roll back TR2. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found.`

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION TR1; 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION TR2
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TR2
    COMMIT Transaction TR1
```

From [Nesting Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

- Committing inner transactions is ignored by the SQL Server Database Engine
- It is not legal for the transaction_name parameter of a ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement to refer to the inner transactions of a set of named nested transactions. transaction_name can refer only to the transaction name of the outermost transaction

Paul S. Randal explores this further in [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (26/30) nested transactions are real](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post.aspx?id=7900bf29-49ac-47bc-a554-0c5a85df19ed)

The best you can do is use Save points instead and check the Xact_state in your catch and at the end.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION tr1; 

SAVE TRANSACTION tr2; 

CREATE TABLE tab1 
  ( 
     f1 DECIMAL(10, 0) 
  ); 

SAVE TRANSACTION tr3 

INSERT INTO tab1 
VALUES     (1); 

SAVE TRANSACTION tr4; 

INSERT INTO tab1 
VALUES     (2); 

BEGIN try 
    -- change the order of the follwoing two lines around to see the difference
    INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (1 / 0); --Results in a rollback to savepoint
    INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES ('OK');  --Results in a complete rollback

    COMMIT TRANSACTION tr4; 
END try 

BEGIN catch 
    IF Xact_state() = -1 
      BEGIN 
          PRINT 'rollback transaction no other work can be done' 

          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 
      END 
    ELSE 
      BEGIN 
          PRINT 'rollback to savepoint' 

          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION tr4 
      END 
END catch 

IF Xact_state() > 0 
  BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO tab1 
      VALUES     (3); 

      INSERT INTO tab1 
      VALUES     (4); 

      COMMIT TRANSACTION tr1; 

      SELECT * 
      FROM   tab1; 

      DROP TABLE tab1 
  END
```

Comment: Please use 
"INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES ('ok'); --Results in a rollback to savepoint"
instead of
"INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (1 / 0); --Results in a rollback to savepoint"

Comment: if you insert 'OK' then transaction will not remain and error occures "The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction."