# Nested transaction can't be rolled back

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I have SQL Server 2008 and want to do such a transaction:

```
begin transaction oo;

......

begin try        
    save transaction xx;
    alter table ....; -- this will fail
    alter table ....;
    alter table ....;
end try
begin catch  
    rollback transaction xx; -- error here
end catch;

......

commit transaction oo;
```

At `rollback transaction xx;`, I get the message

> 3931 The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update** To explain the scenario:

- There is a big transaction "oo", which will change the table structures of the database from product version X to product version Y.
- In the nested transactions, user-specific-tables should be **tried** to be changed (= inner transaction).
- If an user-specific-table is somehow corrupted, the whole product-upgrade process should not be rolled back.
- On the other hand, the user-specific-tables should not be upgraded if something else failed during the main product table upgrade (outer transaction).

Comment: Where do you begin transaction xx?

Comment: Nested transactions are a myth. You can do some things that can sort of mimic a nested transaction but it is far better to just accept they don't exist and rethink your process. There are hundreds of pages explaining the myth of nested transactions. Here are a couple of them. http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/ http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2015/05/26/sql-myth-nested-transactions-in-sql-server-and-hidden-secrets/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057198/how-to-manage-nested-transaction-with-try-catch)

you have to use this line inside `CATCH` block

```
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

which will rollback all transaction, 
when you use this one in your above statement (posted in Q) then it will 
give us error

> The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

for it you have to put this line in `TRY` block

```
COMMIT TRANSACTION oo;
```

then finally your statement like that

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION oo;

BEGIN TRY        
    SAVE TRANSACTION xx;
    CREATE TABLE test (ID INT); -- this will fail from second time
    SELECT 3;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION oo;
END TRY

BEGIN catch  

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 
END CATCH;
```

**UPDATE** after comment

```
BEGIN TRY        
    BEGIN TRANSACTION xx1;
    select 1; -- this will always success
    COMMIT TRANSACTION xx1;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION xx2;
    CREATE TABLE test (id int); -- this will fail from second time
    COMMIT TRANSACTION xx2;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION xx3;
    select 3; -- this will fail from second time
    COMMIT TRANSACTION xx3;


END TRY

BEGIN catch  

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
END CATCH;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Alas, this is not exactly what I am looking for. I have following scenario: There is a big transaction "oo", which will change the table structures of the database from product version X to product version Y. In the nested transactions, user-specific-tables should be tried to be changed. If an user-specific-table is somehow corrupted, the whole product-upgrade process should not be ruined. On the other hand, the user-specific-tables should not be upgraded if  something else failed during the main product tables (outer transaction).